# Replacing the task scheduler in Java with a custom-built one

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm in the process of researching a topic that has to do with schedulers and VMs. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320595/replacing-the-task-scheduler-in-c-sharp-with-a-custom-built-one) yesterday, and I need to know whether the same is possible in Java.

I was wondering, then, if I can change the task scheduler that maps tasks to the real OS threads in Java.

Comment: what "task scheduler" in java?

Comment: @jtahlborn: Hah. Just assumed Java had a task-based model of parallelism... it doesn't? (!) Are all just threads 1:1 to OS threads?

Comment: Threads are 1:1 with OS threads in pretty much all modern jvms.  there are third-party libraries w/ the concept of tasks/actors (like akka), but not much built into the jdk (i guess jdk 7 has the fork/join framework).  so, in order to answer your question, you'd have to pick a specific task framework.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Let us assume the thread pools in util.java.concurrent... What does the scheduling there?

Comment: the OS, like i said.  java threads are 1:1 with OS threads.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Hm, back to the drawing board then. Thanks for your time.

Comment: so why don't you directly interact with OS? or maybe you would have 2nd. agent application that do it so

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342863/controlling-the-java-scheduling-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[On Linux there is a one to one mapping of Java threads to operating system threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125101/one-to-one-mapping-of-java-thread-to-linux-thread-lwp). So on Linux the Java thread scheduler is the kernel scheduler. So to change the Java thread scheduler you would have to alter the kernel. I believe Linux has several options for changing the behaviour of the kernel scheduler, which might be enough for what you need.

If you are *really* trying not to have that one to one mapping, you would have to alter the JVM.

As both the Linux kernel and JVM (the Open JDK version) are open source this is technically possible,  although a lot of work.